How to say "elegance" (so the noun for the adjective "elegant")?
How to say "elegance" (so the noun for the adjective "elegant")?
The sentence I have in mind is:

Patience is a kind of elegance.

Apparently the word "风度" seems the most fitted (一个人的风度) but the Pleco dictionary indicates it's for men.
I don't know if 优雅 can be used here (another dictionary gives this sentence 真正的优雅不是让人们注意，而是使人们回想。):

耐心是一种优雅.


Yes, 优雅 can be an adjective or a noun

@TangHo And it's correct that 风度 is specifically used to refer to men?

风度(demeanor) --> 紳士風度 (gentlemanly demeanor)-->  有紳士風度 ( have gentlemanly demeanor) --> 有風度 (short for 有紳士風度)

quote: "风度 is specifically used to refer to men"  Actually, 有風度 is often used as a shorthand for "有紳士風度" as for the term 风度 itself, it is neutral. For example, 伊利沙伯從小就有貴族風度 (Elizabeth has a noble demeanor since she was a child). 風度 (demeanor) is similar to 風範 (style)

I think 美德 is better.
耐心是一种美德。

As a native Chinese speaker, I rarely use "优雅" as anything other than an adj.

Yes, I agree that 耐心是一种美德 seems more appropriate as "patience", (whether in English or Chinese), has no observable physical characteristics which words like 优雅, 风度 would imply. For the sake of discussion, how about 耐心是一种好气概 ?

Hi, I feel your response points to the fact that Chinese people would not say a sentence like "Patience is a kind of elegance.", or in other words, that the word "elegance" in this sense doesn't exist in Chinese. The word 美德 is loaded with other meanings which are not connotated in "elegance" (like the 德 virtue; although "elegance" in the sense of the example sentence is also not related to aesthetics, 美).

I found an article 《耐心是一种美德》, perhaps it would be helpful to read its contents to determine whether "美德" expresses the word "优雅".
https://epaper.gmw.cn/wzb/html/2015-07/14/nw.D110000wzb_20150714_1-05.htm

@Starckman, yes you're right. "优雅" is more of a written word for us.
